# related categories issue

Tags: templates, categories, related-entries

I am having a slight issue with grabbing data from my related categories. [click here](http://bodyworksforme.com/?/blog) on my dev site i have several categories energy, relax, wellness etc etc. When the user click on one of the categories a blog roll is created which reveals all posts with that category. I have added the following code to my template:

```
<ul class="results-row">
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" disable="member_data|trackbacks" related_categories_mode="yes" limit="4" }
        <li>
        <a href="{url_title_path='blog/full-post'}">
            <div class="featured-tab {categories}{category_image}{/categories}"></div>
            <img src="{blog_slide_image}" alt="placeholder" class="feature-preview-img"></a>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars="150" append="..."}{feature_copy}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
        </ul><!-- RESULTS-ROW ENDS HERE-->
```

However the blog roll pages remain blank, although the categories are populated. Looking at my code above can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue may lie with the presence of the [related_categories_mode](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode) parameter, which is intended for a single entry view and not an entries loop returning multiple entries.

From the docs:

```
  When enabled, this parameter alters the behavior of the {exp:channel:entries} tag, causing it to ignore the entry ID or URL title found in the URL, and instead show a list of entries that are in the same category as the entry specified in the URL. This lets you create a list of entries that are “related” to the primary one specified by the URL.
```

And so your URLs in category viewing wouldn't have a single entry's url title or id, and so the loop fails to return entries.  You would want to use related categories mode on your full-post template perhaps, but not on your list view.